# Multi screens are not aligning properly

Tags: windows-7, multiple-monitors

I am using (4) Samsung (SMB2230) screens. When I place my mouse on the first screen at the bottom right and pull it into the second screen the mouse jumps to the middle on the left of the second screen. Then it does the same on the 3rd and 4th screens. The biggest jump is between the 1st and 2nd then it tightens up between 2 and 3 then close between 3 and 4.

This is a really pain because my mouse gets hung up and I have to move up and down to get it to change screens.I had (4) Dells screens before and this didn't happen. I'm using Windows 7

Comment: are all the monitors side-by-side ? Are their position correctly represented in the windows screen configuration ? could you paste a print screen for us ?

Answer (score 4):

**Right click** on the desktop, click **screen resolution**.  Kinda on top, where you see your monitors with a number... drag and drop to align them.

You should notice the jump increase and decrease with the alignment.

Ensure that the screens are lined up on the bottoms.
**Also, when in the "screen resolution" screen, press "Identify" to recognize each monitor. You can then drag and drop the numbered screens in order to sort them the same way they're align on your desk (same order should be on your screens and in the window)

Answer (score 1):

As Wizlog said, make sure the displays are lined up properly (they should snap into place when you almost dragged them in line), but also check that the resolutions are set the same. I know you have 4 of the same monitor, but if the resolution on one is set differently, it won't line up.

Answer (score 0):

I've been having this problem since win10 came out. With previous Windows versions it would display the top left pixel coordinates of the screen you were rearranging, but that is now missing from win10, plus it seems to snap and join around 15 pixels misaligned each and every time, then even trying with Ctrl/Shift it never aligns correctly.

Solution is to use Nvidia Control panel (if you have Nvidia graphics) to rearrange your multi-screen layout, as their tool still has the pixel coordinates and also snaps perfectly as you would expect!